# ASP.NET CheckBoxes to Enable/Disable Textbox in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, textbox, code-behind

In my markup (Default.aspx), I have a simple table:

```
<asp:Table id="myAspTable" runat="server" />
```

I my code behind (Default.aspx.cs), I have an integer (n) which can be anything from 1 to 100:

```
int n = getValueOfN();
```

Based on this number, I can create checkboxes and textboxes dynamically and add them to my page:

```
CheckBox[] checks = new CheckBox[n];
TextBox[] texts = new TextBox[n];

for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    checks[i] = new CheckBox();
    texts[i] = new TextBox();

    tblrow = new TableRow();
    tblcell = new TableCell();
    tblcell.Controls.Add(checks[i]);
    tblcell.Controls.Add(texts[i]);
    tblrow.Controls.Add(tblcell);
    myAspTable.Controls.Add(tblrow);
}
```

I now want to add the following functionality: Each checkbox i must enable or disable textbox i, when checked/unchecked respectively. How do I do this 100% in the code-behind?

Here is what I have tried:

```
checks[i].AutoPostBack = true;
checks[i].CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(this.CheckToggleEnable);


public void CheckToggleEnable(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Implementation here
}
```

But this doesn't work because I have no way of referencing Textbox i in the CheckToggleEnable function. Also, I was hoping to do this without a post-back.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP.Net, if you create a control **dynamically**, you need to recreate it back when it is posted back to server.

Basically, n should not be dynamic in your code.  Otherwise, we do not know how many control we need to recreate in postback.

The following code will retrieve the sibling **TextBox** once a **CheckBox** is checked.

```
<asp:Table ID="myAspTable" runat="server" />

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int n = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var checkBox = new CheckBox();
        var textBox = new TextBox();

        var tblrow = new TableRow();
        var tblcell = new TableCell();
        tblcell.Controls.Add(checkBox);
        tblcell.Controls.Add(textBox);
        tblrow.Controls.Add(tblcell);
        myAspTable.Controls.Add(tblrow);

        checkBox.AutoPostBack = true;
        checkBox.CheckedChanged += CheckBox_CheckedChanged;
    }
}

protected void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var checkbox = sender as CheckBox;

    var textbox = checkbox.Parent.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
        .Select(control => control)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (textbox != null)
    {
        string value = textbox.Text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

On each checkbox set:

```
AutoPostBack="True"
```

Which posts back to the server everytime one is clicked.  You can attach to the CheckChanged event, and then find the correct textbox and set:

```
Enabled="True"
Enabled="False"
```

Depending on the condition.

I would advise, if you have a lot of checks, to do this in client-side JavaScript because of the performance of posting back to the server repeatedly... it can be intensive on the server.